# How to display date and time with timezone in flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to display the date ,time and time zone in given format "2020-07-08T02:44:58 +05:30".
I could display time and date but couldn't display timezone along with that.help please

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function `DateTime.now().timeZoneName` that will output the timezone's name (EST, PST) if you need further enhancements, you could try this library: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_timezone

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for getting timestamp for flutter.I used package date_format 1.0.8 https://pub.dev/packages/date_format. The package helps me to meet my requirement.